# Microsoft Basic Office 2007 Activation Keys won't work after re-installing on my Laptop

Tags: microsoft-office, upgrade, microsoft-office-2007, windows-activation, license-key

So, I've upgraded my hard-drive on my laptop, and proceeded to grab my trusty copper-faced Official MS Office disk to do an install.  I have three licenses with the fancy green-blue paper that identifies the license keys.

Problem is, that for each of these license keys, when the Office 2007 software asks that I enter the "Product Key" it states:

> The key is incorrect. Verify that you have the correct key, and then retype it

Why would Microsoft want to inhibit/prohibit re-installs on the same machine that the software was initially installed to?

Incidentally, the same goofy error happens with **each** of the three valid product key (activation keys) that I enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the message you get for a failed activation, this is actually a wrong key message.

Check that you are using the correct installation media and not a different disk.

Comment: I have thee disks that are superficially looking identical, but each came from a different sleeve.  The one I originally installed to my HP has the markings on the disk face: "MS OFfice Basic 2007 with Office Professional 2007 Trial".  I may have inadvertently used similar disk: "MS Office Basic 2007", that came w/ a Dell CPU. I'm guessing I used the wrong one last night. Do I need to do a 1) uninstall; and 2) reinstall, using correct disk?

Comment: @Rolnik - yes, that is the best way to do it.

Comment: 5-8 minutes to uninstall the "MS Office Basic 2007" & 3-5 minutes to install "MS OFfice Basic 2007 with Office Professional 2007 Trial" -- activation code accepted!  @Wil thanks for your help!